# Create a notebook inside another notebook in Databricks Dynamically using Python

Tags: python, databricks

I am trying to create a notebook inside another notebook , the created notebook should contain both python code and sql code (using  % sql ,% python ) .I need to run the created  notebook from the parent notebook once it is created .Can anyone suggest a better way to do this .

I found something like **dbutils.notebook.run()** -which will help me to run the already existing notebook , but seeking a method to create a notebook first and run it later .Any suggestion is appreciable!!

Comment: can you explain why you need to do it dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `import` command of the [Databricks Workspace REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#import).

Something like this (put the notebook content into `content` value):

```py
import requests
import os
import json
import base64

ctx = json.loads(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson())
host_name = ctx['extraContext']['api_url']
host_token = "your_PAT_token"
notebook_path = ctx['extraContext']['notebook_path']
new_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(notebook_path), 'New name')

content = "some code"

data = {
  "content": base64.b64encode(content.encode("utf-8")).decode('ascii'),
  "path": new_path,
  "language": "PYTHON",
  "overwrite": True,
  "format": "SOURCE"
}

response = requests.post(
    '{host_name}/api/2.0/workspace/import',
    headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {host_token}'},
    json = data
  ).json()
```

Comment: 1) I assume that 'true' will be 'True' - reserved word for python?
2) Please give me understanding to what you mean by 'extraContext', is that a reserved word or a place holder?

Comment: `extraContent` is a field in the context dictionary

Comment: In that case, will the api_token be auto generated or it should be supplied (excuse my naivety)?

Comment: right now it's autogenerated, but really it's better supply it explicitly because it's not guaranteed that will be kept

Comment: Got an error ` 'error_code': 'MALFORMED_REQUEST', 'message': 'Invalid JSON given in the body of the request - failed to parse given JSON' `

Comment: sorry, instead of `data = data` it should be `json = data`

Comment: When I change the notebook content from the default you used (e.g. "some new code for new notebook"), I get 
```Could not parse request object: Illegal white space character (code 0x20) as character #4 of 4-char base64 unit: can only used between units\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] ```. 
Any reason for this error and how to solve it?

Comment: found another bug - forgot to base64 encode payload

Comment: Asked a trailing question to this at <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71050754/dynamically-insert-a-command-into-an-existing-notebook-in-databricks> . Please assist if you can.