# Dynamically insert a command into an existing notebook in Databricks

Tags: python, json, databricks, databricks-rest-api

Off the back this great answer in this post:
[Create a notebook inside another notebook in Databricks Dynamically using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67580306/create-a-notebook-inside-another-notebook-in-databricks-dynamically-using-python/67581272?noredirect=1#comment125576792_67581272)
where it was shown how to create an entirely new notebook dynamically, my question is on inserting a command into an existing notebook.

Given that

```
ctx = json.loads(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson())
notebook_path = ctx['extraContext']['notebook_path']

content = "some code"
```

is it possible to append `content` into the notebook at `notebook_path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no separate separate API for appending a code to the notebook. But you can use [Workspace API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html) to export given notebook, decode base64-encoded content, append the code, and import it again with `overwrite` parameter set to the `true`.

It's better to add following line:

```
# COMMAND ----------
```

to the begin of your new code so it will be treated as a new cell in the notebook.

Also, the permissions of the notebook could be reset, and if you want to avoid that, then you can use [Notebook Permissions API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/permissions.html#tag/Notebook-permissions) to retrieve current permissions, and then set it back after import.